# Validating datetime using regex on laravel

Tags: regex, laravel

Laravel regex date validation is not working as I expect, the regex is supposed to match `09:00:00` to `16:00:00` in the time portion is an iso datetime, however it's giving an internal server error:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'datetime'  => 'required|date|after:tomorrow|regex:/((0[9]|1[0-5]):[0-5][0]:00)|(16:00:00)$/g',
            'subject'   => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => '500',
                'success'   => 'false',
                'error'     => $validator->messages()
            ]);
        }
```

If I try it again without the regex the validation works as intended and it will insert into the datetime field, I suspect it's trying to match the regex against the date object rather than its string representation, but I don't know where to go from here the docs don't cover regex in detail.

Ideally, I'd like it to display an error message along the lines of 'Enter a time between 9am and 4pm, on the hour only' rather than just fail.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the regex should be `regex:/^((09|1[0-5]):[0-5][0-9]:00|16:00:00)$/` but most probably you'd need an array here rather than `|` separated arguments.

Comment: no it shouldn't, the ^ makes it invalid because this is the second portion of the string, I'm testing the time of a datetime: https://regex101.com/r/WHkR1L/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-regex) (emphasis mine):

> Note: When using the regex pattern, ***it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters***, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

So, try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'datetime'  => [
         'required',
         'date',
         'after:tomorrow',
         'regex:/((0[9]|1[0-5]):[0-5][0]:00)|(16:00:00)$/',
     ],
     'subject'   => 'required|max:255',
]);
```

<sub>***Note:*** *I removed the `g` flag since it is unecessary. The expression will either match or it won't -- no need to find all of the matches globally.*</sub>

---

As far as updating the error messages returned by the `Validator` class, you can simply [pass an array of messages as the 3rd param](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-error-messages):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'datetime'  => [
         'required',
         'date',
         'after:tomorrow',
         'regex:/((0[9]|1[0-5]):[0-5][0]:00)|(16:00:00)$/',
     ],
     'subject'   => 'required|max:255',
], ['datetime.regex' => 'Custom regex error here.']);
```

Comment: okay thanks I did see that but assumed that it was allowed (maybe it shouldn't say **may**), how would I go about adding a custom message? Do I need to create a whole new validator class or can I just add an argument to this?

Comment: @CraigHarley they could definitely word that better. As far as I can tell, it's not necessary unless you use pipe delimiters in your expression. I've updated my answer to explain custom messages.